# How can I get cookie from httpclient?

Tags: android, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I used httppost to login a bbs.
The httpclient can save cookie and other information automatically.
I want to get cookie for httpclient and save it.
So next time I can give the cookie to httpclient and I can visit the bbs again.
So my question is how to get cookie from httpclient.
and how to save the cookie.
and how to set httpclient used the cookie.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://host/stuff");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
try {
    List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Please note you will need to use the official [Apache HttpClient port to Android](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

Comment: I think you forgot to do something with context?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Header[]     headers = null;
HttpResponse response = null;
HttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);                
HttpPost     post = new HttpPost(URI.create(this._strBaseUrl));




 response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

After request returned, extract cookie via:

```
headers = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
```

Then You can iterate through cookie values ( if necessary).